# chrome extention canvas not drawing images inside loop

Tags: canvas, google-chrome-extension, html5-canvas

I am trying to make a screenshot extention that takes a screenshot of the entire page by moving the window with scrollTo and stitching the images together on a canvas in a popup.  However, my problem is that, all of the images im getting back are not being draw/not showing up on the canvas.

popup.js

```
function draw(ctx, image, x ,y) {
  console.log(image);
  var img = new Image();
  img.src = image;
  img.onload = function() {
    ctx.drawImage(img, x, y);
    console.log('x',x);
    console.log('y',y);
  };
}

function screenshot(response) {
  console.log('screenshot');
  var canvas = document.getElementById('imagecanvas'),
    fullHeight = response.height,
    fullWidth = response.width,
    visibleHeight = response.visibleHeight,
    visibleWidth = response.visibleWidth,
    x = 0,
    y = 0;

  canvas.height = fullHeight;
  canvas.width = fullWidth;

  var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
  // console.log('canvas', canvas);
  // console.log('context', ctx);
  //start at the top
  window.scrollTo(0, 0);

  while (y <= fullHeight) {
    chrome.tabs.captureVisibleTab(null, {
      format: 'png'
    }, function (image) {
      draw(ctx, image, x, y);
    });

    // console.log('x',x);
    // console.log('y',y);

    y += visibleHeight;
    window.scrollTo(x, y);
  }
}

chrome.tabs.query({
  'active': true,
  'currentWindow':true
}, function(tab){
  console.log('sending message');
  chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tab[0].id, {
    message: 'dom'
  }, function(response){
    console.log('response', response);
    screenshot(response);
  });
});
```

popup.html

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Chrome Snapshot</title>
    <style>
    #imagecanvas {
      z-index: 100;
    }
    </style>
    <script src="jquery-2.0.2.min.js"></script>
    <script src="popup.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <canvas id="imagecanvas"> </canvas>
  </body>
</html>
```

content.js

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(
  function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
    if (request.message === 'dom') {
      sendResponse({
        height:         document.height,
        width:          document.width,
        visibleHeight:  window.innerHeight,
        visibleWidth:   window.innerWidth
      });
    }
  });
```

manifest.json

```
{
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "name": "test",
  "description": "Save images and screenshots of sites to Dropbox.",
  "version": "1.0",
  "permissions": [
    "<all_urls>",
    "tabs"
  ],
  "browser_action": {
    "default_icon": "icon.png",
    "default_popup": "popup.html"
  },
  "background": {
    "scripts": [
      "jquery-2.0.2.min.js"
    ],
    "persistent": false
  },
  "content_scripts" : [{
    "all_frames": true,
    "matches" : ["*://*/*"],
    "js" : ["content.js"],
    "run_at": "document_end"
  }]
}
```

**Edit in response to Rob's comment**

Heres what I have so far: I can see the page being scrolled, but now, the images from captureVisibleTab returns as undefined.

popup.js

```
var ctx,
    fullHeight,
    fullWidth,
    x,
    y,
    visibleHeight,
    visibleWidth;

function draw(ctx, image, x ,y) {
  console.log(image);
  var img = new Image();
  img.src = image;

  img.onload = function() {
    ctx.drawImage(img, x, y);
    // console.log('x',x);
    // console.log('y',y);
  };
}

function next(tabID) {
  chrome.tabs.captureVisibleTab(null, {
    format: 'png'
  }, function(image) {
    console.log(image);
    draw(ctx, image, x, y);
    y += visibleHeight;

    if (y < fullHeight) {
      chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tabID, {
          message: 'scroll',
          x: x,
          y: y
      }, function() {
        next(tabID);
      });
    }
  });
}

function screenshot(response, tabID) {
  console.log('screenshot');
  var canvas = document.getElementById('imagecanvas');

  fullHeight = response.height;
  fullWidth = response.width;

  visibleHeight = response.visibleHeight,
  visibleWidth = response.visibleWidth;

  x = 0,
  y = 0;

  canvas.height = fullHeight;
  canvas.width = fullWidth;

  ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

  chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tabID, {
        message: 'scroll',
        x: x,
        y: y
    }, function() {
      next(tabID);
    });
}

chrome.tabs.query({
  active:true,
  lastFocusedWindow:true
}, function(tab){
  var tabID = tab[0].id;
  console.log('sending message', tabID);
  chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tabID, {
    message: 'dom'
  }, function(response){
    console.log('dom info', response);
    screenshot(response, tabID);
  });
});
```

content.js

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(
  function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
    if (request.message === 'dom') {
      sendResponse({
        height:         document.height,
        width:          document.width,
        visibleHeight:  window.innerHeight,
        visibleWidth:   window.innerWidth
      });
    } else if (request.message == 'scroll') {
      window.scrollTo(request.x, request.y);
        sendResponse();
    }
  });
```

Comment: Try `document.createElement('img');` instead of `new Image();`. There's a bug in the implementation of the Image constructor - see [http://crbug.com/245296](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=245296 "Invoking new Option(), new Image(), new Audio() DOM constructors in a page invalidates the same constructor at the content scripts (and vice versa)")

Comment: no that didn't solve it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code has two significant issues.

The first problem is that you're assuming that `window.scrollTo(0, 0);` scrolls the tab's content. This is not true, it scrolls your popup's document.

The second problem is that you're calling an asynchronous method in a loop which changes the `y` variable on each iteration. In the callback of this `captureVisibleTab`, you're reading the `y` variable again, but since all callbacks are called when the loop has ended, it's always the same value.

This value is also wrong, by the way. You're looping until `y <= fullHeight`. This should actually be `y < fullHeight`, because once you've reached the bottom of the page, there's no need to take another screenshot.

At the bare minimum, you need to change your loop to a (recursive) set of callbacks.

```
// popup.js
  function next() {
    chrome.tabs.captureVisibleTab(null, {
      format: 'png'
    }, function (image) {
      draw(ctx, image, x, y);
      y += visibleHeight;

      window.scrollTo(x, y); // TODO
      next();
    });
  }
  // Initialize recursion
  next();
```

This method is slightly better, at least you see something being painted on the canvas. It's still not correct though, because you're still calling `window.scrollTo` in the popup script. The correct way to approach this is to delegate the `scrollTo` method to the content script, and use [message passing](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging.html) to invoke the scroll. For example:

```
// popup.js
      //window.scrollTo(x, y); // TODO
      //next();
      chrome.tabs.sendMessage(null, {
          request: 'scroll',
          x: x,
          y: y
      }, next);

// contentscript.js
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function(message, sender,sendResponse) {
    if (message.request == 'scroll') {
        window.scrollTo(message.x, message.y);
        sendResponse();
    }
});
```

One final suggestion: Instead of inserting the content script in all tabs, I recommend to use the [activeTab permission](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/activeTab.html) and [`chrome.tabs.executeScript`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs.html#method-executeScript) to insert the content script when needed. This makes your extension less heavy, and eliminates the need for the `<all_urls>` permission.

Comment: how would i send a message without the tab id when I use activeTabs? Using null for tabid doesn't work https://gist.github.com/raptrex/5982555

Comment: @Raptrex The [`chrome.browserAction.onClicked`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/browserAction.html#event-onClicked) event receives an argument of the `Tab` type which provides the ID as the `id` property.

Comment: Can't use browserAction.onClicked because: `Fired when a browser action icon is clicked. This event will not fire if the browser action has a popup.`

Comment: @Raptrex [`chrome.tabs.query({active:true,lastFocusedWindow:true}, function(tab) { /* do something with tab.id */});`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs.html#method-query)

Comment: I updated my post based on your comments - the images returning from captureVisibleTab are returning undefined

Comment: @Raptrex You're not waiting for the response. `next(tabID)` immediately calls the function. Wrap it in an anonymous function to get that part to work.

Comment: doing `var next = function(tabID)` and `function() { next(tabID) }` in the sendTabMessage callback doesnt work

Comment: @Raptrex In your popup.js from the question, replace both occurrences of `next(tabID)` with `function(){ next(tabId); }`. After doing that, the extension works fine for me.

Comment: i edited my update to show my latest popup.js and image is still returning as undefined

Comment: @Raptrex That code works fine for me. Because of the structure of your extension, you have to refresh the page after reloading your extension. To overcome this issue, inject the content script dynamically, when your popup page is loaded using [`chrome.tabs.executeScript`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs.html#method-executeScript).